# UIView Black Screen in Google Maps iOS

Tags: ios, maps, screen

After joining the Google Maps project covers the default application screen, which are already added objects. Trying to implement it to a UIView application screen turns black.
I would like to add it to the element UIView.

Please help.

.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *mapViewWithFrame;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *btnLocate;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet GMSMapView *mapView_;
```

.m

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:54.104382
                                                            longitude:22.9403031
                                                                 zoom:15];
    self.mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.mapView.bounds camera: camera];
    self.mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    // Add as subview the mapview
    [self.mapViewWithFrame addSubview: self.mapView_];
```

Comment: I restart my simulator. It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I am also get the same issue. im using this code getting correctly, try this

1) Add subview in uiviewcontroller

2) Set custom class name in "GMSMapView" in identity inspector

3) add .h file in this code

`@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet GMSMapView *mapView;`

4) in .m file add this code in viewDidLoad

```
-(void)viewDidLoad  { 
[super viewDidLoad];
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude: 11.066853 longitude: 76.9460043 zoom: 17];
[self.mapView animateToCameraPosition:camera];

GMSMarker *marker = [ [GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(11.066853, 76.9460043);
marker.title = @"Tet Festival 2015";
marker.snippet = @"VAYA Tet";
marker.map = self.mapView;
self.mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal;
}
```

5) uiviewcontroller should mapping the uiview in "GMSMapView" this object

Comment: It works, but does not show the coordinates and zoom on a map

Comment: I am getting the same issue, I have restarted the simulator... So please try it